# Find determinant using shortcuts

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\ 
11&12&13&14&15\\16&17&18&19&20&\\21&22&23&24&25\end{bmatrix}$

I recognize that as I go down a column, the succeeding entry is 5 more than the last. I don't know how to take advantage of this pattern to find the determinant in an efficient manner. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make two of the same rows using elementary row operations. This shows that the matrix is noninvertible, which means the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is useful.

Perform $R_1 \leftarrow R_1-R_2$ and then $R_2 \leftarrow R_2 - R_3$ and you can conclude about your determinant.